# Difference between sort and minimum

Tags: matlab, sorting, minimum

```
Let a matrix 

Z = 
    10,     1,          6,          2;
    0.55,   0.56,   0.57,   0.58;
    0.35,   0.36,   0.37,   0.38;
```

Question 1: I want to obtain the elements that correspond to the minimum element in the first row. In matrix Z, the element 1 in row 1, column 2 is the minimum. So, I should get `(0.56,0.36)`. I applied

```
 [element,index]=    min(z,[],2)
```

but the syntax is incorrect.
I also learnt that `sortrows()` can arrange elements in ascending or descneding order.
How can I apply these 2 functions to do the task?

Question 2: I want to know what is the difference between `sortrows()` and `min()` and will they return different results?

Comment: Put some thought into what you're doing so you don't make things more complicated than they need to be. I have no idea why you'd want to use `sortrows`. You want the minimum of the first row, so limit your search to that `[~, c] = min(Z(1,:));`. This gives you the column, which you use to index: `A = Z(2:end, c);`

Comment: Are you looking for the smallest number in the *entire matrix*?

Comment: @Bob: I agree with detagging titles (I'll explain that to the OP when I get a moment) but there is a community view that themes do not actually need to be removed from titles. Here the title could be `What is the difference between sort and minimum in Matlab?` - this makes it easy to understand when it appears in the Hot Questions sidebar, for example.

Comment: SKM: regarding adding "tags" to titles, such as your `Matlab:` prefixes; the community has [discussed that](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/253028) and decided that we would rather have titles in plain English. I think they are ideal as a question, with a question mark at the end, but this is not mandatory.